# Mixed model with nlme accounting for autoregression, with multiple random effects

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have searched the web, found similar questions, but just not the same one. Here is my problem:

I am trying to analyse the effect of temperature range (T.range) on turtle activity (odba_mean).
I have multiple daily measurements for multiple individuals (name_ID) from two species. I have data for 3 years (no ID repeats over the years).
Activity (mean_ODBA) measures appear to be temporally autocorrelated, so this needs to be accounted for.

I am fairly new to mixed models, so I am very unsure about my code. I am using the nlme package because this seems to one that can more easily account for autoregression.
However, I am having problems specifying multiple random effects.

This is the code I have:

```
Mlme <- lme(odba_mean ~ T.range + species + T.range*species,
             random = ~ T.range|species/name_ID,
             data = df3,
             correlation = corAR1(form = ~date|species/name_ID))
```

I have a couple issues that I cannot seem to solve:

1. I get the warning: "Warning message: In pt(-abs(tVal), fDF) : NaNs produced" which appears to be due to the nesting structure, but I just do not know how to fix it. Or if I should just ignore this.
2. I cannot figure out how to include year as another random effect. I read that it is very difficult in nlme to include multiple random effects that are not nested. I suppose technically name_ID is nested in years, but it is already nested in species, and species is not nested in years (but crossed). How do I incorporate this?

This is part of the data:

```
 name_ID   name year species       date Jday  T.range  odba_mean T.range.qu
1  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-11  132 3.630952 0.06125982   13.18382
2  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-12  133 4.507440 0.01687152   20.31702
3  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-13  134 3.392361 0.03059397   11.50811
4  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-14  135 4.951389 0.02250526   24.51625
5  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-16  137 5.362847 0.02542538   28.76013
6  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-17  138 6.307292 0.04627075   39.78193
7  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-18  139 6.208333 0.03905372   38.54340
8  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-19  140 4.828125 0.04999669   23.31079
9  Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-20  141 7.390625 0.04744481   54.62134
10 Alison_2020 Alison 2020 Painted 2020-05-21  142 6.901042 0.05230780   47.62438
....
```

```
> str(df3)
'data.frame':   2013 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ name_ID   : Factor w/ 48 levels "Alison_2020",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year      : int  2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 ...
 $ species   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Blandings","Painted": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ date      : Date, format: "2020-05-11" "2020-05-12" "2020-05-13" "2020-05-14" ...
 $ T.range   : num  3.63 4.51 3.39 4.95 5.36 ...
 $ odba_mean : num  0.0613 0.0169 0.0306 0.0225 0.0254 ...
```

Comment: Fitting a variable with three levels (year) as a random effect seems rather a stretch to me.

Comment: I would get the model working first and then investigate the pt() problem. Your diagnosis is rather cryptic but I do not have a detailed grasp of the more complex mixed models. If all else fails here try the R-si-mixed-models mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the warning: "Warning message: In pt(-abs(tVal), fDF) : NaNs produced" which appears to be due to the nesting structure, but I just do not know how to fix it. Or if I should just ignore this.

Don't ignore it.

From the output and description, I believe the error may be due to using `species` as a fixed effect and also as a grouping factor for random intercepts. This is a very questionable thing to do in my opinion anyway (what does it mean for a factor to be fixed *and* random ?), but since you have only 2 species it really does not make sense at all to fit random intercepts for it, since you are asking the software to estimate a variance for a variable with only 2 observations. Yes, it can be technically be done, but how reliable would it be ?

> I cannot figure out how to include year as another random effect. I read that it is very difficult in nlme to include multiple random effects that are not nested. I suppose technically name_ID is nested in years, but it is already nested in species, and species is not nested in years (but crossed). How do I incorporate this?

Why do you want year to be a random effect ? `nlme` does not support crossed (ie not nested) random effects. There are some workarounds but I have never found them satisfactory.  I would include year as a fixed effect (either as numeric: 0,1,2... or as categorical)

Comment: As far as I understood it, species is only a fixed effect. The random effect is ID which is nested in species. Species is not the random effect, but it needs to be considered in the random effect structure because ID belong to certain species. What is another way to account for this?

I want year as a random effect because I have no hypothesis about the effect of year, it is merely a factor which may account for some variation. I don't really want to know the effects of year but still have to account for it. I was under the impression this is where random effects come in?

Comment: *" want year as a random effect because I have no hypothesis about the effect of year, it is merely a factor which may account for some variation. I don't really want to know the effects of year but still have to account for it. I was under the impression this is where random effects come in"*. That can be on criteria for choosing a factor as a fixed effect, but it's perfectly valid to treat it as fixed, just as you would a potential confounder  or competing exposure that you are not intersted in interpreting.

Comment: A more common criteria for treating a factor as random is when you have many levels of of it (10s, 100s) and treating it as fixed would be a) cumbersome and b) consume a lot of degrees of freedom.